# clojure check if value in vector in vector in vector equals another

Tags: vector, clojure

Basically I have  vectors within vectors, within vectors, and those deepest vectors contain two coordinate points. for example 
[[[3 4] [4 5]] [[5 6] [6 7]]]
I want to check to see if a certain x and y value match any of the coordinate points inside, and if they do, return -1. I tried doing this but the function isn't working.

```
    (defn check-for-stuff
      [vect x y]
      (if (not (empty? vect)) 
        (dotimes [n (count vect)]
          (if (not (empty? (vect n)))
            (dotimes [p (count (vect n))]
              (if (and (= (((vect n) p) 0) x)
                       (= (((vect n) p) 1) y))
                -1
                ))))))
```

Comment: Why use this data structure? If you're going to be searching for whether given contents exist, something indexed -- a set or a hash-map -- will be much faster (amortized O(1) rather than O(n)).

Comment: ...and, well, as an added bonus that'll just mean you can use `(contains? points point)`. (Comparing `x` and `y` separately is silly, when you can just compare the pairs as units).

Comment: ...also, in Clojure in general, anything with `do` in the name should be used for side effects, not computation.

Comment: FYI -- first cut at the answer had some bugs; edited it to something that's actually tested now.

Comment: ...btw, why `-1`? It would be conventional to return either `nil` or `false` if no match is found, and any truthy value (which is to say, anything other than `nil` or `false`) otherwise.

Comment: but wait how do I convert these vectors into sets. Due to do the way my program works, I need to have seperate sets of coordinates, all contained in a single data structure

Comment: honestly -1 was just the first value that came to mind lol

Comment: It looks like your pairs represent something like segments on a plane.  If so, you want to check whether a point [x y] is one of the ends of any of your segments. You want to have a map start -> end, where each one of those is a point. E.g. {[1 2] [3 4] [2 5] [4 7] ...} etc. You probably want to include the reverse mappings end -> start too.

Comment: actually I'm programming the game Go, and each of the vectors in the big vector represent separate regions, and each regions contains the coordinates of its points

Comment: ...so you have two sets. Or you can have one map structure, where the keys are [x y] pairs and the values indicate which color/side a vector belongs to. Take a look at the (brilliant) implementation of Conway's Game of Life in the O'Reilly book Clojure Programming for some more thoughts on representing coordinate points sparsely in an elegant, easy-to-compose way.

Answer (score 1):

For a literal answer to the question, this is my first top-of-head attempt:

```
(defn check-for-stuff [vect x y]
  (when (some (fn [v] (some #(= % [x y]) v)) vect)
    -1))
```

Observed values in testing:

```
(check-for-stuff [[[1 2] [3 4]]] 1 2)
-1

(check-for-stuff [[[1 2] [3 4]]] 1 3)
nil
```

That said -- the above is bad practice, since it needs to iterate through the vectors provided (and thus having O(n) performance), rather than being able to do a constant-time membership check as a hash-map or set can.

Also, it would be more conventional to return a more meaningful value for a truthy result, or `true` if no such meaningful value exists.

Answer (score 1):

@CharlesDuffy is right on the money about this not being the ideal structure for something like this. Based on your description of what you're doing, I would recommend a set of sets of x-y vectors (representing points). For example:

```
#{#{[3 4] [4 5]} #{[5 6] [6 7]}}
```

This is a set that represents 2 planes, each represented as a set of x-y vectors. To determine whether any of these sets contains a given x-y point, you can use `some` and `contains?`, like this:

```
(defn check-for-stuff [planes x y]
  (some #(contains? % [x y]) planes))
```

As @CharlesDuffy also pointed out, `-1` might not be the best value to use as a return value. The idiomatic thing to do in Clojure when you're writing a function that checks inside a collection for a specific value and tells you whether it's in there or not, is to take advantage of the way that "truthiness" works in Clojure. Every value is considered "truthy" except for `false` and `nil`. In the function above, `some` returns either the plane containing `[x y]` if it exists in `planes`, or `nil`. You can use the return value of this function just like it were returning `true` or `false`, like this:

```
(if (check-for-stuff #{#{[3 4] [4 5]} #{[5 6] [6 7]}} 4 5)
  (println "point found")
  (println "point not found"))
```